# In Ruby, how do I make a hash from an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a simple array:

```
arr = ["apples", "bananas", "coconuts", "watermelons"]
```

I also have a function `f` that will perform an operation on a single string input and return a value. This operation is very expensive, so I would like to memoize the results in the hash.

I know I can make the desired hash with something like this:

```
h = {}
arr.each { |a| h[a] = f(a) }
```

What I'd like to do is not have to initialize h, so that I can just write something like this:

```
h = arr.(???) { |a| a => f(a) }
```

Can that be done?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Say you have a function with a funtastic name: "f"

```
def f(fruit)
   fruit + "!"
end

arr = ["apples", "bananas", "coconuts", "watermelons"]
h = Hash[ *arr.collect { |v| [ v, f(v) ] }.flatten ]
```

will give you:

```
{"watermelons"=>"watermelons!", "bananas"=>"bananas!", "apples"=>"apples!", "coconuts"=>"coconuts!"}
```

Updated:

As mentioned in the comments, Ruby 1.8.7 introduces a nicer syntax for this:

```
h = Hash[arr.collect { |v| [v, f(v)] }]
```

Comment: I think you meant `... { |v| [v, f(v)] }`, but this did the trick!

Comment: Just one thing - why's there a `*` next to `*arr.collect`?

Comment: @Jeriko - the splat operator `*` collects a list into an array or unwinds an array into a list, depending on context. Here it unwinds the array into a list (to be used as the items for the new hash).

Comment: So `Hash[]` takes a list (with an even number of items) in terms of `key,value,key,value...`?

Comment: @Jeriko Yes - if you give `Hash[]` an odd number of arguments, it blows up. See here for more on the splat operator (which is really very useful in a number of contexts): http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/the-splat-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: `ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash` :) Thanks

Comment: After looking at Jörg's answer and thinking this over some more, note that you can remove both `*` and `flatten` for a simpler version: `h = Hash[ arr.collect { |v| [ v, f(v) ] } ]`. I'm not sure if there's a gotcha I'm not seeing, however.

Comment: In Ruby 1.8.7, the ugly `Hash[*key_pairs.flatten]` is simply `Hash[key_pairs]`. Much nicer, and `require 'backports'` if you haven't updated from 1.8.6 yet.

Answer (score 61):

Did some quick, dirty benchmarks on some of the given answers. (These findings may not be exactly identical with yours based on Ruby version, weird caching, etc. but the general results will be similar.)

`arr` is a collection of ActiveRecord objects.

```
Benchmark.measure {
    100000.times {
        Hash[arr.map{ |a| [a.id, a] }]
    }
}
```

*Benchmark @real=0.860651, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.8500000000000005, @total=0.8500000000000005*

```
Benchmark.measure { 
    100000.times {
        h = Hash[arr.collect { |v| [v.id, v] }]
    }
}
```

*Benchmark @real=0.74612, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.010000000000000009, @utime=0.740000000000002, @total=0.750000000000002*

```
Benchmark.measure {
    100000.times {
        hash = {}
        arr.each { |a| hash[a.id] = a }
    }
}
```

*Benchmark @real=0.627355, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.010000000000000009, @utime=0.6199999999999974, @total=0.6299999999999975*

```
Benchmark.measure {
    100000.times {
        arr.each_with_object({}) { |v, h| h[v.id] = v }
    }
}
```

*Benchmark @real=1.650568, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.12999999999999998, @utime=1.51, @total=1.64*

### In conclusion

Just because Ruby is expressive and dynamic, doesn't mean you should always go for the prettiest solution. The basic each loop was the fastest in creating a hash.

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome for doing your homework and posting it :)

Comment: Slightly faster to use a manually incremented loop variable: I don't have your dataset - I just cooked a trivial object with an @id accessor and more-or-less matched your numbers - but direct iteration shaved a couple of % off.  Stylistically, I prefer {}.tap { |h| .... } to assigning a hash, because I like encapsulated chunks.

Comment: I'm a little confused at the difference between `arr.map` and `arr.collect` considering that `.collect` is merely an alias to `.map`

Answer (score 42):

Ruby 2.6.0 enables a shorter syntax by [passing a block to the `to_h` method](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#to_h-with-a-block):

```
arr.to_h { |a| [a, f(a)] }
```

Answer (score 34):

```
h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |v,h| h[v] = f(v) }
```

Comment: This reads a lot more concisely than using Hash[arr.collect{...}]

Comment: This is incredibly slow, check out my post below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27962063/1761067

Answer (score 11):

This is what I would probably write:

```
h = Hash[arr.zip(arr.map(&method(:f)))]
```

Simple, clear, obvious, declarative. What more could you want?

Comment: I like `zip` as much as the next guy, but since we're already calling `map`, why not leave it at this? `h = Hash[ arr.map { |v| [ v, f(v) ] } ]` Is there an advantage to your version that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Telemachus: With all the Haskell code I've been reading, I just got used to point-free programming, that's all.

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing it like described in this great article http://robots.thoughtbot.com/iteration-as-an-anti-pattern#build-a-hash-from-an-array

```
array = ["apples", "bananas", "coconuts", "watermelons"]
hash = array.inject({}) { |h,fruit| h.merge(fruit => f(fruit)) }
```

More info about `inject` method: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Comment: This does a ```merge``` for every step of the iteration. Merge is O(n), as is the iteration. Thus, this is ```O(n^2)``` while the problem itself is obviously linear. In absolute terms, I just tried this on an array with 100k elements and it took ```730 seconds```, while the other methods mentioned in this thread took anywhere from ```0.7``` to ```1.1 seconds```.

Yes, that's a slowdown by *Factor 700*!

Answer (score 3):

in addition to the answer of Vlado Cingel (I cannot add a comment yet, so I added an answer).

Inject can also be used in this way: the block has to return the accumulator. Only the assignment in the block returns the value of the assignment, and an error is reported.

```
array = ["apples", "bananas", "coconuts", "watermelons"]
hash = array.inject({}) { |h,fruit| h[fruit]= f(fruit); h }
```

Comment: I benchmarked the two versions: the use of merge doubles the execution time. The above inject version is a comparabe to the collect version of microspino

Answer (score 1):

Another one, slightly clearer IMHO -

```
Hash[*array.reduce([]) { |memo, fruit| memo << fruit << f(fruit) }]
```

Using length as f() -

```
2.1.5 :026 > array = ["apples", "bananas", "coconuts", "watermelons"]
 => ["apples", "bananas", "coconuts", "watermelons"] 
2.1.5 :027 > Hash[*array.reduce([]) { |memo, fruit| memo << fruit << fruit.length }]
 => {"apples"=>6, "bananas"=>7, "coconuts"=>8, "watermelons"=>11} 
2.1.5 :028 >
```