# How do you use map to get a hash instead of an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently using the following to get an array of a certain field in a table:

```
Classrooms.all.map(&:teacher_name)
```

This returns the following:

```
["James", "Josh", "Peter"]
```

What I want is a hash instead so something like the following where I can include the teacher_id:

```
{"James" => "1", "Josh" => "2", "Peter" => "3"}
```

I tried using `Classrooms.all.map(&:teacher_name, &:teacher_id)` but it gives me a syntax error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it the old-fashioned way:

```
pairs = Classrooms.all.map {|t|
  [t.teacher_name, t.teacher_id]  # [key, value]
}
hash = Hash[pairs]                # in /old/ ruby: Hash[*pairs.flatten]
```

.. or whatnot.

See [In Ruby, how do I make a hash from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943422/in-ruby-how-do-i-make-a-hash-from-an-array)

Comment: Can I do all of this in one line?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. Just take the value assigned to `pairs` and shove it where `pairs` is used (without assigning it first) .. e.g.: `hash = Hash[Classrooms.all.map {|t| [t.teacher_name, t.teacher_id] }]` Now, will you be able to understand/maintain this in the future? That's the real goal :)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.6.0 enables a [shorter syntax](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#to_h-with-a-block):

```
Classrooms.all.to_h { |t| [t.teacher_name, t.teacher_id] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is not to use each at all. Use each_with_object instead. It is designed for what you are trying to do.

```
Classrooms.all.each_with_object({}) { |c, hash| hash[c.teacher_name] = c.teacher_id }
```