# How do I do a simple array to hash conversion?

Tags: ruby

I have an array `[1,2,3]` and want to create hash from it, so the result is `{"kangaroo"=>1, "moose"=>2, "mouse"=>3}`. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Does "last" really mean the last element of the array...?

Comment: no, just a random word, will update it

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943422/in-ruby-how-do-i-make-a-hash-from-an-array) this question had solved!!

Comment: Where do you take the animal names from?

Comment: "From my head :) " is not a good answer when people are trying to help you. What would be the source of the values `"kangaroo", "moose", "mouse"` in your code.

Comment: Just to clarify, the comment for the animal names source was I believe after I received correct answer, so I thought it was some kind of joke question. And answer should be "These are some random words from my head. It was first,last,random at the beginning but they made too much confusion, so I replaced them with some random words". Sorry for this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about:

```
Hash[%w(kangaroo moose mouse).zip [1,2,3]]
# => {"kangaroo"=>1, "moose"=>2, "mouse"=>3}
```

#### Explanation

[`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) combines both arrays element-wise:

```
%w(kangaroo moose mouse).zip [1,2,3]
# => [["kangaroo", 1], ["moose", 2], ["mouse", 3]]
```

[`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) creates a Hash from this array.