# Better way for array to hash conversion

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-1.9

I have an array and I want to convert it to a hash. I want the array elements to be keys, and all values to be the same.

Here is my code:

```
h = Hash.new
myarr.each do |elem|
  h[elem] = 1
end
```

One alternative would be the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943494/46461). I don't think it's very different from the solution above.

```
h = Hash[ *myarr.collect { |elem| [elem, 1] }.flatten ]
```

Is there a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [`Hash[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) is quite happy to get an array-of-arrays so you can toss out the splat and `flatten` and just say this:

```
h = Hash[myarr.map { |e| [ e, 1 ] }]
```

I suppose you could use [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead:

```
h = myarr.each_with_object({}) { |e, h| h[e] = 1 }
```

Another option would be to [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) your `myarr` with an appropriate array of `1`s and then feed that to `Hash[]`:

```
h = Hash[myarr.zip([1] * myarr.length)]
```

I'd probably use the first one though.

Answer (score 6):

The code OP wrote, can also be written as :-

```
a = %w(a b c d)
Hash[a.each_with_object(1).to_a]
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}
```

And if you have Ruby version >= 2.1, then

```
a.each_with_object(1).to_h
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ruby 2.1:

```
myarr.map{|e| [e,1]}.to_h
```

Another clever way (from comment by @ArupRakshit):

```
myarr.product([1]).to_h
```

Comment: The OP clearly said they are using Ruby 1.9.3 (Although I moved that to ruby-1.9 tag).

Comment: Ah, OK. Perhaps I'll delete.

Comment: I'd leave it here, people will presumably come across this question when they're just looking for general Ruby solutions so this is a worthwhile answer.

Comment: You're right, @Arup. I [knew that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22315036/182590) :) Fixed.

Comment: +1 for telling my way is clever. :-) The fact is I also knew that, but as you wrote 2.0, I lost my confidence, and had to go to the doco for double checking it..

Comment: It's not just clever, it's the shortest solution and it still maintains clarity. (That being said, your use of each_with_object is cool too).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, using [`cycle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle):

```
Hash[a.zip([1].cycle)]
```

Comment: I also really like this answer for its simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

```
a.each_with_object({}){|e, h| h[e] = 1}
```

Comment: Note: This was earlier than another answer that posts exactly the same solution without hesitation.

Comment: 7s earlier because I took the time to correct their misunderstanding about the `Hash[]` arguments and I took the time to include other solutions.

Comment: Timeliness in itself shouldn't translate to votes. Once this post is 2 years old, nobody will care when the answers arrived. However, if it indicated someone was taking credit for someone else's answer, it would be a problem. This is clearly not the case here.